# css fixed div on left

Tags: css

I am trying to do 2 sides page separated by divs. 1 of them is content, other one is sidebar.

Sidebar must be positioned on the left side.

And here is the code I am currently using to do it:

```
#SideBar
{
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: #727272;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}

#Content
{
 float: left;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 300px;
 padding: 3px;
 font-size:12px;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

First time it seem working correctly but when I go to restore down (resizing) my browser, it brokes.

Divs which positioned in sidebar are overflowing. Yes, I am talking about inside elements of sidebar.

Why sidebar not staying fixed on the left?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My html is:

```
<div id="SideBar">
 Sidebar content goes here
</div>
<div id="Content">
 Main content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with overflowing?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: @TurnItUp The problem is, that I don't understand your problem. :-)

Comment: @Oliver I meant with overflowing, getting out of its container.

Comment: Floating has no effect on an element with `position:absolute`. This is as per the W3C spec. Either choose floating, or choose absolute positioning.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Okay. I choose absolute positioning. There is still problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments below, Adding a min-height attribute should solved it.

Comment: Content is not inside the sidebar.

Comment: So is content aligned to right of the sidebar, if so put in float:right?

Comment: You got a link with it running?

Comment: Hard to see what's going wrong then.. As the methods above should work.. Are the two divs set in a larger container?

Comment: Ooooh man, thanks for suggestion. You gave me inspiration.

Adding min-height attribute is solved problem.

Comment: No worries.. I'll add as an answer for people in the future.. if your mark it as answer correct thats cool